# PDF File downloads incorrectly in browser, but fine with wget or curl with NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I have an application in nodejs/express that generates a PDF and streams it in the response. When I perform a request via curl or wget the file downloads just fine.

When I perform the request on a browser, the file is not downloaded correctly. Curiosly, the file size is way bigger (is 59k when downloaded with wget/curl but 101k when downloaded in the browser)

Here's the snippet that generates the response:

```
fs.readFile('file.pdf', function(err, data) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + req.params.id + '.pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');                
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', data.length);
  res.status(200).end(data);
});
```

I don't know if I'm missing a header or if there's something in the request that I should be paying attention to that I'm not, but I have no idea why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980323/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-through-javascript

Comment: While they're also serving a PDF, I don't have a direct exposure of the file via express. The problem turned out to be encoding. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own.

Had to change this line

```
res.status(200).end(data);
```

to

```
res.status(200).end(data, 'binary');
```

Once I changed it, the pdf was sent perfectly.

If the encoding is not set, Express attempts to write it as UTF-8 (which produces the undesired result).

Will keep this into account whenever sending binary files through Express.